# Question about metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove, that for any infinite set $X$, there exists some metric $d$ such that $X$ has a limit point under $d$.

Comment: This question is cleary missing context.

Comment: I know, but the task is truly that short, what else should I write? :)

Comment: You could start by what metric are you referring to?

Comment: I mean that for every X, you can give a metric, it can be anything, but with this metric, X must have a limit point.

Comment: I've edited the original post. @Atvin should review my edit to make sure I've correctly represented the question.

Comment: Yeah, it is correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any infinite countable subset $x, x_0, x_1, \ldots$ of $X$.
Define the distance $d$ by :
$$d(x_i,x_j)=\left|\frac{1}{2^i}-\frac{1}{2^j}\right|$$
$$d(x,x_i)=\frac{1}{2^i}$$
and for all $z \in X$, for all $y \in X - \{x,x_0,\ldots\}$ :
$$d(z,y)=1.$$
You can check that this defines a distance, and that for this distance the sequence $(x_n)$
converges to $x$.

Comment: A very nice answer, thank you! :)